# Accurately distort graphics

Tags: graphics

I would like to accurately distort this plot of $\sin(x^{1/2})$ (and others like it) so that the wavelengths are evened out (ie - "inverse-square root" it).

[image]

I should like to do the same to "de-log" plots too.

I have no idea where to start though.

Comment: Well, if $f(x) = \sin(x^2)$, you could just plot $f(\sqrt x)$ instead? Pretty sure what you have there's not [a plot of $\sin(x^2)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20sin%28x%5E2%29) though.

Comment: Yes, `sin(x^2)` should be zero at the origin.

Comment: Sorry - corrected. I would like to distort images with this proportion - the plot was just an eg

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this, but you probably need to be more specific.  The words "accurate" and "distort" seem to be at odds.  One way would be `Sin[Sqrt[x]] /. x -> x^2/1000`.  Another, if you want to "morph" the graphs would be `(1 - t) Sqrt[x] + t x / Sqrt[1000]`, for `t` running from 0 to 1.  That's assuming `x` ranges from `0` to `1000`.

Comment: It is images really that I would like to distort - including the axes etc. I shall probably have to reword it in the morning!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
plt1 = Plot[Sin[Sqrt[x]], {x, 0, 1000}, ImageSize -> 400];

ticks = Ticks /. AbsoluteOptions[plt1, Ticks];
ticks = MapAt[#^(1/2) &, ticks, {{1, All, 1}}];
plotrange = PlotRange[plt1];
plotrange = MapAt[#^(1/2) &, plotrange, {1}]; 

plt2 = Graphics[plt1[[1]] /. Line[x_] :> Line[{#[[1]]^(1/2), #[[2]]} & /@ x], 
                PlotRange -> plotrange, Ticks -> ticks, plt1[[2]]];
Row[{plt1, plt2}]
```

[image]

**Update:** The approach above works without issue in Version 9.0.1.0 (Windows 8 64bit). Unfortunately it does not work in Version 10 because `AbsoluteOptions` stopped working as expected in Version 10. A work-around until the `AbsoluteOptions` glitch is fixed (hopefully in Version 10.0.1.0) is to specify the ticks directly:

```
ticksb = {{#^(1/2),#}&/@FindDivisions[{0,1000},{5}][[1]],Automatic};
plt2b = Graphics[plt1[[1]] /. Line[x_] :> Line[{#[[1]]^(1/2), #[[2]]} & /@ x], 
            PlotRange -> plotrange, Ticks -> ticksb, plt1[[2]]];
Row[{plt1, plt2b}]
```

[image]

Comment: brilliant! Thank you!

Comment: I am getting the following errors ... any ideas?
`Axes::axes: {{False,False},{False,False}} is not a valid axis specification. >>``
Axes::axes: {{False,False},{False,False}} is not a valid axis specification. >>``
Ticks::ticks: {Automatic,Automatic} is not a valid tick specification. >>``
Ticks::ticks: {Automatic,Automatic} is not a valid tick specification. >>``
Axes::axes: {{False,False},{False,False}} is not a valid axis specification. >>``
General::stop: Further output of Axes::axes will be suppressed during this calculation. >>`

Comment: do I need to load a package?

Comment: @martin, this works without issue with in 9.0.1.0 (Windows 8 64bit). Just confirmed that it does not work in Version 10  because `AbsoluteOptions` stopped working es expected in Version 10.  I will try to find a workaround to handle the ticks. (The rest of the code works if you you comment out the parts involving `ticks`)

Comment: Great, thanks :)

Comment: Works perfectly - thank you!

Comment: it doesn't seem to like it if I replace `#^(1/2)` with `Log[#]`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Martin, I think `Log[0]` (`Indeterminate`)  in `ticksb` and `plotrange` is the source of the problem. You can either (1) change the range `{0,1000}` to `{1,1000}` or (2) use `ticksb /. Indeterminate->0` instead of `ticksb` and similarly for `plotrange`.

Comment: Great, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an attempt to do this using the internal options used by `LogPlot` etc.  It has the advantage of correctly working with the adaptive sampling of `Plot` to produce a better result with extreme scaling.

```
SetAttributes[scaledPlot, HoldRest]

scaledPlot[scfn_, exp_, {s_, r1_, r2_}, arg___] :=
 With[{inv = InverseFunction[scfn]},
   Plot[exp, {s, scfn[r1], scfn[r2]}, arg, 
     Method -> {"MappingFunctions" -> {{#1, #2} &, {#1, #2} &}, 
                "DomainMappingFunctions" -> {inv}},
     Ticks -> {Charting`ScaledTicks[{scfn, inv}], Automatic}
   ]
 ]
```

Examples:

```
scaledPlot[Sqrt, Sin[x^(1/2)], {x, 0, 1000}]
```

[image]

```
scaledPlot[#^(1/4) &, Sin[x^(1/4)], {x, 0, 2*^6}]
```

[image]

Compare the second result with the same plot using kguler's method and the value of adaptive sampling becomes apparent:

```
plt1 = Plot[Sin[x^(1/4)], {x, 0, 2*^6}, ImageSize -> 400];
ticksb = {{#^(1/4), #} & /@ FindDivisions[{0, 2*^6}, {5}][[1]], Automatic};
plt2b = Graphics[plt1[[1]] /. Line[x_] :> Line[{#[[1]]^(1/4), #[[2]]} & /@ x], 
  PlotRange -> plotrange, Ticks -> ticksb, plt1[[2]]]
```

[image]

The more extreme the scaling the worse this problem will become, and adding `PlotPoints` will not overcome it.  (e.g. try `x^(1/9)`)

**Note:** Sometimes the tick marks disappear, e.g. with `#^(1/3) &`.  This seems like a problem with `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` but one can always specify a list of ticks manually if necessary.

Comment: this is really great - should have waited before accepting :/ Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to use this with ListLinePlot?

Comment: @martin (1) Thanks.  (2) Yes, I recommend waiting a bit longer before Accepting an answer.  However, if you feel so inclined you can change (or remove) your Accept at any time. (3) I don't believe these Method options apply to `ListLinePlot`, but since you wouldn't get adaptive sampling there anyway a manual scaling approach seems reasonable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - really great answer - I feel a bit mean unaccepting an answer though ... :/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment and if I understand it correctly, you want to work with the image itself. If so, maybe something like this would help.

```
img = Plot[Sin[Sqrt[x]], {x, 0, 1000}];

 ImageTransformation[img, {#[[1]]^2, #[[2]]} &]
```

Comment: I tried it, expecting to point out that the tickmarks would look awful. They do. But actually,  even the graph itself looks pretty ghastly.

Comment: if he use PlotPoints -> 100 the plot could be better.