# How to use Charting`ScaledFrameTicks to produce tick specifications for log-scaled plots?

Tags: plotting, graphics, ticks

For reasons I laid out in an [earlier thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133360/2464), I want to use the undocumented functions `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` and `` Charting`ScaledFrameTicks `` to generate tick specifications for plots.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to use these functions to generate tick specs for log-scaled plots.

I'm using the following "reference plot" as a test case:

```
reference = LogLinearPlot[Tanh[x], {x, 1, 100}, ImageSize -> Small, 
                          Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

My question is:

**What values must I give to the `transforms`, `min`, `max` arguments in the assignment**

```
xticks = Charting`ScaledTicks[transforms][min, max];
```

**...such that x-axis ticks in the plot produced by**

```
LogLinearPlot[Tanh[x], {x, 1, 100}, ImageSize -> Small,
              Ticks -> {xticks, Automatic}]
```

**...resemble those in the `reference` plot?**

**IMPORTANT:** I want to stress that replicating the `reference` plot is not the goal here.  Rather, the goal here is *an explicit list of tick specifications (primarily coordinates and labels), as generated by a call to `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` with suitable parameters*.  In this question, the `reference` plot only serves as a quick way to check that these tick specifications are correct.

---

Apparently, the `reference` plot itself uses `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` under the hood:

```
First[Ticks /. Options[reference]]
Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}]
```

BTW, the expression `` Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}] `` does not evaluate to an explicit list of tick specifications, so it is not the answer to this post's question.

In any case, using `` Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}] `` as tick specification, like this

```
LogLinearPlot[Tanh[x], {x, 1, 100}, ImageSize -> Small,
              Ticks -> {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], Automatic}]
```

...results in the error

> Tick specification must be a list or a function.

---

**What I've tried so far**

Here's my first attempt (I eyeballed the endpoints 0.75 and 150 from the `reference` plot):

```
With[{xticks = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][0.75, 150]},
 Column[{
   LogLinearPlot[Tanh[x], {x, 1, 100}, ImageSize -> Small, 
    Ticks -> {xticks, Automatic}],
   TableForm @ tickCoords @ xticks  (* see end of post for for definition of
                                       tickCoords *)
   }]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(The table after the plot shows the x-coordinates and labels for the labeled x-axis ticks.)

There are a couple of problems with this, but the most serious one is that the tick labels (10, 10<sup>11</sup>, ..., 10<sup>61</sup>) are way off.

(Also, compared to the `reference` plot above, this one has much fewer tick marks.  That's also something I'd like to correct.)

I figured that maybe the range's endpoints need to be specified in log units, which led to my second attempt:

```
With[{xticks = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][Log[0.75], Log[150]]},
 Column[{
   LogLinearPlot[Tanh[x], {x, 1, 100}, ImageSize -> Small, 
    Ticks -> {xticks, Automatic}],
   TableForm @ tickCoords @ xticks  (* see end of post for for definition of
                                       tickCoords *)
   }]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now it is the *position* of the ticks is off, while the labels (1, 5, 10, 50, 100) are at least appropriate to the plot (even if they don't yet match those in the `reference` plot).

I tried many other variants, which either triggered errors, or produced no ticks at all.

---

For the sake of this demonstration, I wrote the following helper function, which just extracts from `` Charting`ScaledTicks ``'s output the coordinates of the labeled ticks:

```
tickCoords[tickSpecs_List] := 
  Cases[Take[#, 2] & /@ tickSpecs, Except[{_, _Spacer}]];
```

I use this helper function to generate the table of x-coordinates and labels shown after each of the plots shown above.

Comment: Related: [(54613)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54613/121#60108), [(59651)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59651/121#59670), both my own posts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have the gist of `` Charting`ScaledTicks ``, but how to feed this as an option to `LogLinearPlot` is a major roadblock here.

First, take the tick marks you get from `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` and rescale the first argument by the inverse of the log function in question

```
Module[{xticks = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][Log[1], Log[100]]},
    xticks[[All,1]] = Exp@*First/@xticks;
    LogLinearPlot[Tanh[x], {x, 1, 100}, ImageSize -> Small, 
      Ticks -> {xticks, Automatic}]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another way is to take the tickmarks you find, and feed them to a wrapping `Show`

```
With[{xticks = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][Log[1], Log[100]]},
   Show[
      LogLinearPlot[Tanh[x], {x, 1, 100}, ImageSize -> Small], 
      Ticks -> {xticks, Automatic}]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: we think alike!

Comment: @MinHsuanPeng - this question really appeals to WRI employees lol

Comment: Now you mentioned it. Indeed! lol

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`TracePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TracePrint.html) to capture the `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` call the FrontEnd uses:

```
Last @ Reap @ TracePrint[
    Rasterize @ LogLinearPlot[Tanh[x],{x,1,100}, Ticks->{Automatic,Automatic}],
    _Charting`ScaledTicks[__],
    TraceAction->Sow,
    TraceInternal->True
]
```

> {{Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log,Exp}][-0.306331,4.9115]}}

It evaluates to:

```
ticks = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log,Exp}][-0.30633099404439457`,4.911501180032486`];
Cases[ticks, {_, _Integer, __}]
```

> {{0.,1,{0.01,0.},{AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}},{0.693147,2,{0.01,0.},{AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}},{1.60944,5,{0.01,0.},{AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}},{2.30259,10,{0.01,0.},{AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}},{2.99573,20,{0.01,0.},{AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}},{3.91202,50,{0.01,0.},{AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}},{4.60517,100,{0.01,0.},{AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}}

The first column is just [`Log`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Log.html) of the second, or in other words, [`Exp`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exp.html) of the first column yields the second column:

```
Cases[ticks, {p_, i_Integer, ___} :> {Exp[p], i}]
```

> {{1.,1},{2.,2},{5.,5},{10.,10},{20.,20},{50.,50},{100.,100}}

Answer (score 6):

Bear in mind that all the visualization functions(`Plot`, `ListPlot`, `BarChart`, etc...) try to parse options in a transformed domain, meaning when you specify to put "label" at `10` in `LogLinearPlot`, it will put "label" at `Log[10]`. So here if we scale back the position, it will work as expected.

This utility is more helpful in `Graphics` or `Show`, when you need to create your own vis function.

```
xticks = MapAt[Exp, Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][Log[1], Log[100]], {All, 1}];
LogLinearPlot[Tanh[x], {x, 1, 100}, Ticks -> {xticks, Automatic}]
```

[image]

or

```
xticks = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][Log[1], Log[100]];
Show[LogLinearPlot[Tanh[x], {x, 1, 100}], Ticks -> {xticks, Automatic}]
```

[image]