# Log scale for ListContourPlot when the axes have different orders of magnitude

Tags: plotting, ticks, undocumented, logarithmic-scale

I am trying to plot a data set ([download here](http://www.wikiupload.com/BA3DE8W1VYNTHA4)) in Mathematica (it's 3.9 MB and I wasn't sure how to best share it) which I then want to visualize with `ListContourPlot`. *Note: the exact data is not really relevant to this question as I am less concerned about what the plot looks like and more interested in the tick marks on the vertical axis and the scale in the legend.*

If I naively try a `ListContourPlot`, I get this image:

```
NTable=Import[]//ToExpression;
data = Flatten[NTable, 1];
plot0 = ListContourPlot[data]
```

[image]

However, I can get Mathematica to interpret this data set using `` Charting`FindTicks `` [from this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68973/listcontourplot-interpolation-fails-if-x-and-y-axes-have-different-scales).

```
data = Flatten[NTable, 1];
trdata = Transpose[data];
ranges = Through[{Min, Max}[#]] & /@ Most@trdata;
plotdata = Transpose@MapAt[Rescale, trdata, {{1}, {2}}];
plot1 = ListContourPlot[plotdata, 
  FrameTicks -> ({#, 
       None} & /@ (Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {##}][0, 1] & @@@ 
       Reverse@ranges)), FrameTicksStyle -> 15, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 180, 
    LegendFunction -> "Frame", LegendMargins -> 5]]
```

[image]

This is a start, though I still want the vertical axis and the legend to be a log scale. Adapting the methodology in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35032/how-to-do-the-log-scale-plot-for-listcontourplot) (I have Mathematica 11.2), I get

```
plot2 = ListContourPlot[data, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {Automatic, "Log10", "Log10"}, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 180, 
    LegendFunction -> "Frame", LegendMargins -> 5]]
```

[image]

I get my log scale on the vertical axis, but not in the legend. But more importantly, Mathematica isn't plotting all the data points. If I try to combine the two methods, I get:

```
plot3 = ListContourPlot[data, 
  FrameTicks -> ({#, 
       None} & /@ (Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {##}][0, 1] & @@@ 
       Reverse@ranges)), 
  ScalingFunctions -> {Automatic, "Log10", "Log10"}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> 15, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 180, 
    LegendFunction -> "Frame", LegendMargins -> 5]]
```

[image]

Now, I am missing most of my tick marks in addition to the data points. What I want is to reproduce the second image, so that my horizontal scale is the same, my vertical scale is $\{1,10,10^2,10^3,10^4,10^5,10^6\}$ and my legend reads something like $\{10^6,5\times10^6,10^7,5\times10^7,10^8,5\times10^8,10^9,5\times10^9,10^{10}\}$.

I have absolutely no idea how to go about doing this. I have a feeling that I can get around this problem using suitable parameters in `` Charting`FindTicks `` (similar to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139040/how-to-use-chartingscaledframeticks-to-produce-tick-specifications-for-log-scal)), but I do not know how to do this.

Comment: seems related: [ListPlot3D weirdly distorts and loses plotting data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/214453/125)

Answer (score 0):

To get your data, you need an paid account. Therefore I try to make up some data and plot it:

```
da = Flatten[
   Table[{x, y, x^2 +  y^79}, {x, 0, 10^7, 10^5}, {y, 1, 1.5, 0.05}], 
   1];
ListContourPlot[da, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log", "Log"}, 
 PlotLegends -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh - I didn't realize it needs a paid account.

I tried the code with a condensed range for the horizontal axis, but Mathematica began cutting off data points:
```da = Flatten[
   Table[{x, y, x^2 + y^7}, {x, 0.4999, 0.5001, 0.00001}, {y, 1, 10^7,
      10^5}], 1];

ListContourPlot[da, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log", "Log"}, 
 PlotLegends -> True]
```

Comment: I think i is a bug and  has to do with sampling. Please send a bug report to support@wolfram.com